# Java — Log file only saving the latest item

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

I am writing an app in Java (new developer) and I am trying to save messages and things like that within a log file (logs/[date].txt). The problem I am getting is that it's overwriting each time, rather than appending the values to my file.

Here is my code:

```
public void onMessage(String channel, String nick, String account, String hostname, String message) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date now = new Date();

    try {
        /* Check if the logs folder exists */
        File logdir = new File("logs/");

        boolean result = true;
        if (!logdir.exists()) {
            try {
                logdir.mkdir();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("[ERROR] Could not make directory 'logs/'");
                result = false;
            }
        }

        /* Check if the log file exists */
        File fcheck = new File("logs/" + sdfd.format(now).replace("/", "-") + ".txt");
        if (!fcheck.exists()) {
            try {
                fcheck.createNewFile();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("[ERROR] Could not make log file 'logs/" + sdfd.format(now).replace("/", "-") + ".txt'");
            }
        }

        /* Write to file */
        if (result) {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("logs/" + sdfd.format(now).replace("/", "-") + ".txt");
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(file);

            String entry = "[" + sdf.format(now) + "] [" + channel + "] " + nick + " (" + account + ") > " + message + "\n";
            write.append(entry);

            write.close();
            file.close();
        }else{
            System.err.println("[ERROR] Could not save line to log file.");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("[ERROR] Could not save line to log file.");
    }
}
```

Sorry if this isn't amazingly clear, but I'm still learning Java.
As you can see, I have `write.append(entry);` — which I thought would append \n to my log file, thus allowing me to save and save and keep all the entries.

Comment: Unrelated, but ugh: refactor the filename creation, and why are you reinventing logging?!

Comment: One advice, don't reinvent the wheel, you can use log4j or java.util.Logger and let them handle files ... Unless you want to learn how it works I encourage you to get some knowledge in those libraries.

Comment: For the form (singnature) of the [`PrintWriter` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)) you use: "*If the file exists then it will be **truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created.*".

Comment: Java devs prefer logging frameworks such as log4j and its family e.g. logback, etc.  These simplify multi threaded logging.

Comment: @DaveNewton How am I supposed to learn if I don't know how the wheel works?

Comment: @user3650841 Depends on what you want to learn--I *personally* would rather focus on more interesting things than logging. It's okay if you want to repeat that kind of thing, I just find it not really something worth doing.

Comment: I'm just trying a range of things out, I'm doing IRC, logging, MySQL and all that fun stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the `PrintWriter` on every entry - a new instance is created everytime you call that method and the file is overwritten.

If you do not want to change this, you can set the `FileWriter` to **append mode** by using [`FileWriter(String, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("logs/" + sdfd.format(now).replace("/", "-") + ".txt", true);
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating object of type File , add second parameter true , and the file will be appended

```
FileWriter fcheck = new FileWriter("logs/" + sdfd.format(now).replace("/", "-") + ".txt",true);
```

Comment: This is the same as the actual answer, so you deserve an up vote too, but I can't give you one yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `append` parameter of [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) to `true`:

```
 FileWriter file = new FileWriter("logs/" + sdfd.format(now).replace("/", "-") + ".txt", true);
```

Comment: You are using `FileWriter(String, boolean)`, not `FileWriter(File, boolean)`.